# How vite import.meta.glob yaml file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yaml, vite

in vite, How import.meta.glob read yaml files

import.meta.glob("../../locales/*.yaml",{eager:true})

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'All' (at en.yaml?import:11:23)

Comment: Did it work without a glob? There seems to be a problem with yaml loader or file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Install [@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n).

**Step 2**

```js
// vite.config.ts
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    VueI18nPlugin({
      include: [path.resolve(__dirname, './locales/**')],
    }),
  ],
})
```

Ensure the correct project directory:

```bash
.
├── README.md
├── locales
│   └── zh-CN.yaml
├── node_modules
├── ...
├── src
│   ├──...
│   ├── plugins
│   │   └── i18n.ts
│   ├── main.ts
│   └── views
└── vite.config.ts
```

Done.